# How to login with Yii2 through twitter account

Tags: php, twitter, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am following the [yii2-user](https://github.com/dektrium/yii2-user/blob/master/docs/README.md)  guide, and I succeed to login through a 
facebook account. Now i want to login through a twitter account and my

```
'consumerKey' => 'h5XFtvRVSxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
'consumerSecret' => 'Zb6lCescDoatl1thwGxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
```

but when I try to login through twitter I get the following error:

```
Request failed with code: 401, message: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hash>
    <error>Desktop applications only support the oauth_callback value 'oob'</error>
    <request>/oauth/request_token</request>
</hash>
</xml>
```

I searched for this error but did not found a suitable solution. This is my login page: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have an answer for my own question.I solved this problem by defining **Callback URL**
while creating api key i take Callback URL as optional due to which i get error.But after defining proper **Callback URL** its working fine for me.

Comment: You got `email_id` of logged in user's twitter account?